# JJTree "IN" and "CONTAINS" realization

Tags: java, javacc

This question will drive me crazy. I have a generated classes which will be able to parse such expression:

```
'is_container AND custom_application_name IN ("myasp.com","fraworks")'
```

and it will be evaluated as:

```
'is_container AND ((application_name CONTAINS "fraworks" IGNORECASE) OR (application_name CONTAINS "myasp.com" IGNORECASE))'
```

but I need it to do in such way:

```
'is_container AND ((application_name IS "fraworks" IGNORECASE) OR (application_name IS "myasp.com" IGNORECASE))'
```

The problem is how jjTree iterates through an array of variants ("myasp.com","fraworks") when processing "IN" literal, find where it uses "CONTAINS" and just put there "IS".

The part of my .jjt file which describes this:

The function which will parse whole expression

```
void DiscreteRangeExpression()#DiscreteRangeExpression(true):
{
Token t=null;
}
{
    ((Variable() TerminalIn() SetLiteral())|(SetLiteral() TerminalIn() Variable()))
//Variable() TerminalIn() SetLiteral()
(
    TerminalIgnorecase()
{
    jjtThis.setIgnorecase(true);
}
)? 
{
    jjtThis.setOccurType(OCCURSANY);
} 
(
    <ALL>
{
    jjtThis.setOccurType(OCCURSALL);
}
    |
    <ANY> 
    |
    (
            <OCCURS> 
            t=<INTEGER_LITERAL>
{
    jjtThis.setOccurType(OCCURSEQUAL);
    jjtThis.setOccurNum(t.image);
} 
        (
                <PLUS>
{
    jjtThis.setOccurType(OCCURSMORE);
}
                |
                <MINUS>
{
    jjtThis.setOccurType(OCCURSLESS);
}
        )?
    )
)?
}
```

Terminal "IN":

```
void TerminalIn() : 
{}
{
    <IN>
}
```

Reserved words:

```
TOKEN :
{
< ALL: ["a","A"]["l","L"]["l","L"] >
| < AND: ["a","A"]["n","N"]["d","D"] >
| < ANY: ["a","A"]["n","N"]["y","Y"] >
| < BETWEEN: ["b","B"]["e","E"]["t","T"]["w","W"]["e","E"]["e","E"]["n","N"] >
| < CONTAINS: ["c","C"]["o","O"]["n","N"]["t","T"]["a","A"]["i","I"]["n","N"]["s","S"]>
| < ENDSWITH: ["e","E"]["n","N"]["d","D"]["s","S"]["w","W"]["i","I"]["t","T"]["h","H"]  >
| < HASKEY: ["h","H"]["a","A"]["s","S"]["k","K"]["e","E"]["y","Y"] >
| < IGNORECASE: ["i","I"]["g","G"]["n","N"]["o","O"]["r","R"]["e","E"]["c","C"]["a","A"]["s","S"]["e","E"] >
| < IN: ["i","I"]["n","N"] >
| < IS: ["i","I"]["s","S"] >
| < MATCH: ["m","M"]["a","A"]["t","T"]["c","C"]["h","H"] >
| < MASK: ["m","M"]["a","A"]["s","S"]["k","K"] >
| < NOT: ["n","N"]["o","O"]["t","T"] >
| < NULL: ["n","N"]["u","U"]["l","L"]["l","L"] >
| < OCCURS: ["o","O"]["c","C"]["c","C"]["u","U"]["r","R"]["s","S"] >
| < OR: ["o","O"]["r","R"] >
| < REGEX: ["r","R"]["e","E"]["g","G"]["e","E"]["x","X"]>
| < STARTSWITH: ["s","S"]["t","T"]["a","A"]["r","R"]["t","T"]["s","S"]["w","W"]["i","I"]["t","T"]["h","H"]>
| < LAST: ["l","L"]["a","A"]["s","S"]["t","T"]>
}
```

Please help me solve this. If there is needed some more information, please ask. Thanks!

Comment: So is it that you just want to produce "IS" nodes where your parser now produces "CONTAINS" nodes?  I don't see where the "CONTAINS" nodes are produced. You have not shown the rule for `SetLiteral`.